# Why does Kira pronounce Bajor differently?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, names, continuity

I'm hardly a linguist, but it's impossible to not notice.

Throughout the show, Major Kira refers to *Bajor* and *Bajoran* with a hard *J*, while everyone else (it seems) uses a soft *J*. Is there any in-universe explanation for this? Perhaps a dialectical thing from the province she was from? Or was it just something that Nana Visitor did--in which case, why?

Comment: I'd be interested to see if anyone can find and interview with cast and crew that explains this, but the most likely explanation is the scripts didn't come with a defined pronunciation and the actors just did the best they could with what they had.

Comment: https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/402.txt - ***"BAJOR = BAY-jor"***. So she's pronouncing it the right way, according to the script notes

Comment: I’ve watched DS9 all the way through twice and never noticed a difference. Can you find some videos showing the difference?

Comment: After reviewing the script notes linked by @Valorum I'll revise my hypothesis to the scripts came with a defined pronunciation, but most of the actors just ignored it.

Comment: @Valorum, but due to the...interesting...properties of English, *BAY-jor* could still end up being pronounced either *BAY-djor* or *BAY-zhor* depending on the person reading it: that's why a IPA is necessary if you want something pronounced precisely.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - This is an American script for American actors. It can only be pronounced one way

Comment: I only vaguely recall Picard pronouncing it different in hindsight rewatching TNG and maybe the ds9 pilot.  Not sure how real that memory is.

Comment: @Valorum, English speakers, even Americans, often use the "zh" pronunciation on foreign words or words perceived as foreign when they encounter a "j", even when it really should be pronounced "hard".

Comment: @Valorum, incidentally, Sudanese-born English actor Alexander Siddig, Irish actor Colm Meaney, and Canadian actor Nicole de Boer wave hello.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - Oh sure, but their pronunciation isn't ever really in question. They can pronounce it however they want

Comment: Bay-jaw-jaw, [not Bay-war-war](https://www.bartleby.com/73/1914.html).

Comment: I asked Garak, and he assured me the correct pronunciation is  "Cardassia Minor".

Answer (score 5):

Due to the nature of English spelling, someone reading *Bajor* could end up being pronounced either *BAY-djor* or *BAY-zhor* depending on the person reading it, because of the way the letter "j" can represent multiple sounds: that's why an IPA spelling is necessary if you want something pronounced precisely (**'be d͡ʒɔɹ**) or (**'be ʒɔɹ**) would be the case.

If someone saw the "j" and assumed it was pronounced like in *June*, there's your "hard j". If someone thought "Aha, foreign word like *bonjour*", then "soft-J". English speakers often do that even if the word *should* have a sound more like the "hard-j". Note how you'll usually hear "Bay-zhing" for the capital of China when it more accurately should be "Bay-dzhing", and how the Indian word *raj* ends up being "razh" instead of the more accurate "radzh".

So it might simply been different cast members interpreting it in different ways.

Comment: This seems to be more of an elucidation of the question than an answer in and of itself.

Comment: It puts forward the possibility that "it was just something Nana Visitor did" compared to other cast members and the reason why. Thus, an answer.

Comment: Anecdotally, I pronounce my own last name differently depending on how fully I'm using my first and middle names. When I'm using the shortened version of my first name, my last name "a" that I pronounce like "anne". When I'm using the full version of my first name, or including my middle name, or using my first two initials in lieu of a name, I pronounce that same letter more like "ahn". (Sorry, I don't know the IPA.)

Comment: @T.J.L. wow, I was pronouncing it `tuh-jul`. I had it totally wrong, my apologies!